# reference to an array of pointers

Tags: c++, c++14

How do I write a reference to an-array-of-pointers as a parameter to a function?

Class B - works. array of integers.

Class A - fails. array of pointers to integers.

```
#include <iostream>

int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int arr[2] = { 1, 2 } ;
int * parr[2] = { &a, &b };

class B // works
{
  int * parr_;
  B(int (&arr)[2] ) 
  {
     parr_ =  arr;
  }
};

class A // doesn't work!
{
  int ** pparr_;
  A(int (*&pparr)[2] ) 
  {
     pparr_ =  pparr;  //error 
      
  }
  
};
```

The error:

```
ERROR!
g++ /tmp/K0oKZ2yIsn.cpp
/tmp/K0oKZ2yIsn.cpp: In constructor 'A::A(int (*&)[2])':
/tmp/K0oKZ2yIsn.cpp:25:16: error: cannot convert 'int (*)[2]' to 'int**' in assignment
   25 |      pparr_ =  pparr;
      |                ^~~~~
      |                |
      |                int (*)[2]
```

Comment: why do you want to pass the array by reference when anyhow you make it decay to pointer?

Comment: please include the error message in the question

Comment: `B(int (&arr)[2] )` is `B( element_type (&arr)[array_size])` and thats the same also with other types of elements

Comment: Using `std::array` can help.

Comment: You wrote the `*` in the wrong place; the syntax is `type (&name)[size]`, so`int* (&pparr)[2]`.

Comment: Typo `A(int* (&pparr)[2] )` or  `A(int* pparr[2] )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `int (*&pparr)[2]` to `int *(&pparr)[2]` as explained below.

---

The **problem** is that currently `pparr` is a **reference to a pointer to an array of size 2 with elements of type `int`**. What you actually wanted(as per your description) is to declare `pparr` as an **reference to an array of pointer to `int`** which can be done by changing the declaration of `pparr` to as shown below.

```
class A // works now
{
  int ** pparr_;
//------v------------------->note the asterisk is moved outside the parenthesis
  A(int *(&pparr)[2] )  //now pparr is a reference to an array of size two with elements of type int*
  {
     pparr_ =  pparr;  //works now
      
  }
  
};
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TaKzq9Yrv)